# Using cockroachdb / postgresql in an iOS swift app

Tags: ios, swift, postgresql, cockroachdb, cockroachcloud

I'm trying to connect to a cockroachdb instance from within an iOS app being developed on Xcode. I am using the [PostgresClientKit](https://github.com/codewinsdotcom/PostgresClientKit). I get an error saying:

```
localizedSeverity: Fatal
code: 0C800
message: codeProxyRefusedConnection: connection refused
```

Has anyone used this library or any other to successfully pull data from cockroach into an iOS app?

I tried the following code:

```
import PostgresClientKit

var configuration = PostgresClientKit.ConnectionConfiguration()
configuration.host = “host.cockroachlabs.cloud"
configuration.database = “server.table”
configuration.user = “username”
configuration.port = 12345
configuration.credential = .scramSHA256(password: “pass”)
let connection = try PostgresClientKit.Connection(configuration: configuration)
```

I was expecting it to connect successfully.

Comment: Replace curly quotes `“` `”` with straight quotes `"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the `host` parameter correctly. Where did you get `host.cockroachlabs.cloud` from?

You should see the hostname for connecting to your CRDB cluster from the connect modal in the cluster overview page.

For example it could look something like this: `klutzy-ent-6246.g8z.cockroachlabs.cloud`

[image: connect modal for my serverless cluster]